# Posting JSON ordered list of values via AFNetworking AFHTTPClient

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking

I know I can post JSON data when setting AFHTTPClient default encoding to AFJSONParameterEncoding then on the call:

```
- (void)postPath:(NSString *)path
      parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters
         success:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject))success
         failure:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error))failure
```

at parameters I can fill in a dictionary which get translate to JSON.

What if I am connecting to a server which request JSON object like this:

["aNiceLayer"]

I don't need at the top level a dictionary but an array object. But parameter dictates a dictionary type, What do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need an array as your base for your request, you should create your own `NSData` object using `NSJSONSerialization`. Create a `NSMutableURLRequest` and `setHTTPBody:` using that data, then create a new `AFJSONRequestOperation` using `initWithRequest:`. Enqueue your request, and it should work just fine.

Comment: By this do you mean to skip AFHTTPClient altogether?

Comment: Maybe I can make an AFHTTPClient category.

Comment: You don't need to skip AFHTTPClient, but you do need to make your own `NSData*` object and add that to the request. A category on `NSMutableURLRequest` sounds more helpful, personally, since you're only using the `AFHTTPClient` to create the request.